# Quartz can't get a JNDI connection to my database?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying to use Quartz to schedule jobs that manipulate data in a MySQL database. I access the database with a JNDI URL setup in the Tomcat app's context. If I start a thread in a ServletContextListener, it all works great. But if I try to run the same code in a Quartz Job, it can't connect to the database. Also, I am using Eclipse.

How do I give the Quartz environment access to the servlet's context?

i.e. I want the Quartz jobs to be able to access the database do do useful work... e.g. send emails.

Comment: Showing part of the code might be needful here.

Comment: It's not a code issue. It's an architecture question... The JNDI resource is defined in the context of the Tomcat app. But it seems that Quartz jobs can not see that context. How can I make the app context visible to the Quartz jobs?